# Define ENUM values in a .plist in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, enums, plist

I use a configuration.plist file to configure certain parameters in my application and initialise few classes based on the contents of this `plist file.`

However I want to expose to the developer a list of options that can be selected as below(per say),

[image]

I can this kind of option available in application `info.plist` file but I don't get to see anywhere else on how I can achieve this. 
I'm looking at getting a drop down list showing the list of available options, Possibly an `ENUM` list.

Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: I don't believe you can do that. The (default) keys and values you are talking about are hard-coded in Xcode to have a nice, localized, human-readable description.

Answer (score -1):

You can read from the .plist file:

```
NSDictionary* infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSString* region = [infoDictionary objectForKey:(__bridge id) kCFBundleDevelopmentRegionKey];
```

Comment: You've misunderstood the question. The question is about how to enable helpful editing of a property list other than the info.plist within Xcode, with drop down options and so forth.